# crystal report date to date query results

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I've query when I run it in the sql server it gives me the correct result ,but I put in my code the result changed?

This is my query

```
String data = "SELECT [dat] ,[product_id] FROM [market].[dbo].[product] where dat>='2012-11-1' and dat='2012-11-1'
```

This is my code

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection (@"Data Source=.\Ahmed;Initial Catalog=Market;Integrated Security=True");
String data = "SELECT [dat] ,[product_id]FROM [market].[dbo].[product] where dat>='2012-11-1' and dat<='2012-11-31'";
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter ad1 = new SqlDataAdapter(data, con);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
ad1.Fill(ds1);
ReportDocument cr  = new ReportDocument();
cr.Load(@"C:\Users\Ahmed\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication9\WindowsFormsApplication9\CrystalReport4.rpt");
cr.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables["product"]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
```

the result in sql server
Product_id dat 
101 2012-11-1 
102 2012-11-1

In C# like this:

product_id dat 
100 2012-10-10 
101 2012-11-1 102